# Javafx преведение типов

Tags: java, javafx

не работает преведение типов
делаю так

```
class NewFeld extends TextField
```

потом в другом классе создаю объект и хочу добавить его в GridPane

```
NewText newText = new NewText();
mainGrid1.add(newText, 1, gridaddFeldNumber);
```

ошибка Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'NewFeld', required: 'javafx.scene.Node
т.е. newText не того же типа, что TextField

```
TextField newImg = new NewFeld();
NewFeld newImg1 = new TextField();
```

так тоже ошибка о разных типах

Comment: `class NewFFFFFFFFFFeld` букву не забыли?

Comment: от руки писала тут, забыла) в идее все гуд

Comment: Работать может только приведение типов, а привидения никак не могут работать - оно же привидение, кто ж его заставит? :D

Comment: а по делу комментариев не будет?

Comment: А так не работает: mainGrid1.add((Node) newText, 1, gridaddFeldNumber); ?

Comment: нет, тоже ошибка с типами

Comment: код написан, ошибка написана. Чего еще не хватает?

Comment: Я запустила этот же пример, у меня никаких ошибок не показывает компилятор

Comment: В классе NewFeld у вас точно TextField типа javafx.scene.control.TextField?

Comment: у меня ошибка уже при написании, подчеркивает красным те строчки, что написаны в вопросе. М.б. идее чего-то не хватает?

Comment: оу, да и правда TextField не тот, а ведь несколько раз переделывала и не обратила внимания, спасибо)

Comment: @Ксения, да не за что :)